# What does "terrific rep" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning

I would like to know the meaning of "terrific rep" as used in the pilot episode of the TV serial "The Office."

Here is the context:

> **Michael:** Question. How long do we have to... [Telephone rings] Oh uh, Todd Packer, terrific rep. Do you mind if I take it? 
> **Jan:**
>   Go ahead. 
> **Michel:** Packman. 
> **Todd Packer:** Hey, you big
>   queen. 
> **Michael:** Oh, that's not appropriate. 
> **Todd
>   Packer:** Hey, is old Godzillary coming in today? 
> **Michael:** Uh,
>   I don't know what you mean. 
> **Todd Packer:** I've been meaning to
>   ask her one question. Does the carpet match the drapes?
>   
> **Michael:** Oh, my God! Oh! That's... horrifying. Horrible.
>   Horrible person.

([officequotes.net](http://officequotes.net/no1-01.php))

Comment: This is too vague to be able to answer succinctly, I'm afraid. Could you at least share the context, as "rep." could be "representative", "reputation" or even "reptile"... while I doubt it's an accolade for someone's dinosaur skills, it can't be ruled out at this stage.

Comment: That expression is from TV Serial "The Office".

Answer (score 1):

In this context, "rep" is an abbreviation for *representative.*

The Wikipedia article on [Todd Packer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Todd_Packer) says that he is the Outside [Sales Representative](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sales-representative) of Dunder Mifflin.

The adjective "[terrific](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sales-representative)" means he is good at his job.

Comment: Thank You very much for Your clear reply. Russian interpreter translated it as " пройдоха; - bounder, rapscallion, wheeler-dealer."